# How to validate user input when a range is involved?

Tags: python, loops, validation, input, range

Hi I'm using book to try to learn python and one of the exercises is asking me this:

3.1 (Validating User Input) Modify the script of Fig3.3.  to validate its inputs. For any input, if the value entered is other than 1 or 2, keep looping until the user enters a correct value. Use one counter to keep track of the number of passes, then calculate the number of failures after all the user’s inputs have been received.

Below is the script. Any ideas on how to make this possible?

```
# fig03_03.py
"""Using nested control statements to analyze 
examination results."""

# initialize variables
passes = 0  # number of passes
failures = 0  # number of failures

# process 10 students
for student in range(10):
    # get one exam result
    result = int(input('Enter result (1=pass, 
2=fail): '))

    if result == 1:
        passes = passes + 1
    else:
        failures = failures + 1

# termination phase
print('Passed:', passes)
print('Failed:', failures)

if passes > 8:
    print('Bonus to instructor')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a while loop checking that `result` is in `[0, 1]`.

Here is a program you can try:

```
# fig03_03.py
"""Using nested control statements to analyze 
examination results."""

# initialize variables
passes = 0  # number of passes
failures = 0  # number of failures

# process 10 students   
for student in range(10):
    # get one exam result
    result = 0
    while result not in [1, 2]:
       result = int(input('Enter result (1=pass, 2=fail): '))

    if result == 1:
       passes = passes + 1
    else:
       failures = failures + 1

# termination phase
print('Passed:', passes)
print('Failed:', failures)

if passes > 8:
    print('Bonus to instructor')
```